# Apply Style after Transform

Tags: wpf

I’ve created a style for labels that adds a drop shadow:

```
<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="BigLabel">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="35" />
    <!-- some more... -->
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0" Opacity="0.9" ShadowDepth="5" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

One of the labels for which I want to use the style is rotated. Now when I apply the style this way:

```
<Label Content="Awesome" Style="{StaticResource BigLabel}" >
    <Label.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
    </Label.LayoutTransform>
</Label>
```

Then the result is that the drop shadow still goes into the same direction viewed from the label’s perspective (lower right), but into a different direction viewed from the user’s perspective (upper right). Now as there are multiple labels, some rotated and others not, I want the shadows to all go into the same direction *viewed from the user’s perspective*, lower right.

That means that either I have to set a different `Direction` on the rotated labels, or to tell WPF to apply the style with the shadow *after* rotating. Now I’m wondering:

Is there a way to tell WPF to first rotate and then apply the style?

Comment: Here I tested using .Net 4.5 in Windows 7 SP1 64 bits, NVIDIA GeForce 9100M G, and it worked OK. Maybe this is a bug there. Also have you tried to use Label.RenderTransform just to test?

Comment: @Tony: The same with `Label.RenderTransform`. I too have .NET 4.5, Win7 SP1 x64, but NVIDIA Quadro NVS 295.

Comment: @Tony: The same with an Intel HD graphics. Don’t know if this is a bug. Are you sure it worked for you? I think I should have clarified: I want all shadows to go into the same direction, lower right, no matter if the label is rotated or not. That is: First rotate, then shadow.

Comment: Here is the picture of the window: https://twitter.com/tonyvca/status/388292046529642496/photo/1

Comment: I have changed this to make more visible:  <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" Opacity="0.92" ShadowDepth="3" />

Comment: @Tony: Thanks for the picture. This is how it looks on my computers. Imagine you have several labels, most of them not rotated. Looks strange IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, use the Direction attribute:

```
    <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="BigLabel">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="35" />
        <!-- some more... -->
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" Opacity="0.92" ShadowDepth="3" Direction="225" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: http://www.google.com.br/imgres?imgurl=http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC56988.png&imgrefurl=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748273.aspx&h=391&w=445&sz=26&tbnid=Orf1zQhQcjC0GM:&tbnh=102&tbnw=116&zoom=1&usg=__BQfgOlX8SiX3rV-Uxz4EcD56HkE=&docid=CEJbSh2FWBYXmM&sa=X&ei=tKpWUv7lF_Wy4AOk34HIBg&ved=0CHgQ9QEwBw

Comment: Simple answer is no. The LayoutTransform will also rotate the Direction angle, so you must choose the Direction for each style/angle according to each style and users perspective. As I did in this answer: the Direction attribute on the rotated label is 225. On a normal label it would be 315. (90 degrees difference)